# do react native remove PropTypes in production by default?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native

I am trying to use PropTypes in my react native project but the only thing that concern me is the performance issue a proptype can bring to my app. so Should I manually remove proptypes in production or react native automatically do this

Answer (score 1):

According to Dan Abramov in this post:
https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/841259251146379266?lang=da

PropTypes are simply replaced with empty shims in production, so don't worry about it.